# Create a list from data and keys

Tags: list, haskell, key, list-comprehension

I have a question about Haskell. I want to know how I can create a list of data from two lists, one with data, an other with some key values. I'll explain it with an example:

Given two lists: `[('a', "red"), ('b', "blue"), ('c', "green")]` and `[('a','b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c','a')]`. Now I want to change the values of the second list with their colors given in the first list. So the function should return `[("red","blue"), ("blue","green"), ("blue","red")]`.

I was thinking about list comprehension, but I'm very new to Haskell and I have no idea how I should do that. Or is there an easier way to do this?

This is probably a dumb question, but if someone can give me an example, I might get used to the think process of Haskell a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- second element from first (head) dropping tuples with bad key
color :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> b
color c = snd.head.dropWhile ((/=c).fst)

recolor a b = map (\(x, y) -> (color x a, color y a)) b
```

running

```
Prelude> recolor [('a', "red"), ('b', "blue"), ('c', "green")] [('a','b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c','a')]
[("red","blue"),("blue","green"),("green","red")]
```

If you consider an element of the second list cannot be found in the first list. You can write

```
color :: Eq b => b -> [(b, a)] -> Maybe a
color c = fmap snd.listToMaybe.dropWhile ((/=c).fst)
```

then

```
Prelude> recolor [('a',"red"),('b',"blue"),('c',"green")] [('a','h'),('u','c'),('c','a')]
[(Just "red",Nothing),(Nothing,Just "green"),(Just "green",Just "red")]
```

(you need `import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)`)

Comment: This answer will give an error when an element of the second list cannot be found in the first list. eppsilonhalbe's answer is better in that it will remove such elements from the answer instead of throwing an exception. Depending on your use case, it might be better to return a `[Maybe (b,b)]` or even a `[(Maybe b, Maybe b)]` instead of a `[(b,b)]`.

Comment: `fmap snd` is clearer and more idiomatic than `maybe Nothing (Just . snd)`. Then again, your second version of `color` is simply [`lookup`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:lookup) by another name.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to use `Map`

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)
import Data.Map (lookup
                ,fromList)
import Prelude hiding (lookup)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let a = [('a', "red"), ('b', "blue"), ('c', "green")]
        b = [('a','b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c','a')]
        table = fromList a
    print $ mapMaybe (maybePair . (\(x,y) -> (x `lookup` table,
                                              y `lookup` table ))) b

maybePair :: (Maybe a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a,b)
maybePair (Just x,Just y) = Just (x, y)
maybePair _ = Nothing
```

## Edit:

with the help of arrows the last anonymous function can be condensed to

```
import Control.Arrow ((***))
[…]
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let a = [('a', "red"), ('b', "blue"), ('c', "green")]
        b = [('a','b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c','a')]
        table = fromList a
        f x = x `lookup` table
    print $ mapMaybe (maybePair . (f *** f)) b
[…]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without need of importing any library but using tail recursion:

```
keyColor = [('a', "red"), ('b', "blue"), ('c', "green")]
keys = [('a','b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c','a')]

colors [] _ = []                            -- no keys returns the empty list
colors _ [] = []                            -- no colors returns the empty list
colors xs ys = colors_helper (xs, ys, [])   -- tail recursion

colors_helper ([], _, acc) = acc
colors_helper (((k1, k2):xs), ys, acc) = 
                colors_helper (xs, ys, acc ++ [(color (k1, ys), color (k2, ys))])
  where
    -- converts value to color
    color (val, ys) = snd $ head $ filter ( \(k, v) -> k == val ) ys
```

test:

```
> colors keys keyColor 
> [("red","blue"),("blue","green"),("green","red")]

> colors keys []
> []

> colors [] keyColor 
> []
```

Comment: This is tail-recursive, but the performance will be pretty poor for for moderate-sized inputs.  You should avoid building up lists by concatenating onto the end.  The usual idioms are to either cons onto the front and reverse after the last recursive step, or to use a difference list (a.k.a. Hughes list) since that supports O(1) snoc.  At any rate, tail recursion in Haskell is over-rated.